# ¿Cómo conservar una variable de una ejecución a otra?

Tags: python

Estoy creando un Calendario y use la opcion de ControlMenu para que el usuario pueda cambiar el color del fondo.
Lo que yo quiero es que cada vez que se ejecute el programa, el color del fondo sea el color que el usuario selecciono anteriormente.
Pero cada vez que lo cierro y lo vuelvo a abrir el color que sale (por defecto) el el "Pink"...

Aqui el codigo:

```
def enero(self, event):
    self.root4 = tk.Toplevel(bg="Pink")
    self.root4.title("Enero")
    self.root4.transient(self.root3)
    self.root4.resizable(False, False)
    self.root4.iconbitmap("D:\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\icono-bela_calendario.ico")
    self.root4.geometry("1366x768")

    self.menu = tk.Menu()
    self.root4.config(menu=self.menu)
    self.opciones1 = tk.Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Violeta clarito", command=self.violeta_clarito)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Violeta fuerte", command=self.violeta_fuerte)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Violeta2", command=self.violeta2)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Verde Agua", command=self.verde_agua)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Azul claro", command=self.azul_claro)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Celeste clarito", command=self.celeste_clarito)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Negro", command=self.negro)
    self.opciones1.add_command(label="Guardar Color", command=self.guardar_color)
    self.menu.add_cascade(label="Colores", menu=self.opciones1)

def violeta_clarito(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#B39DDB")
    self.color = "violeta clarito"

def violeta_fuerte(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#673AB7")
    self.color = "violeta fuerte"

def violeta2(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#9575CD")

def celeste_clarito(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#4FC3F7")

def verde_agua(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#4DD0E1")

def azul_claro(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#42A5F5")

def negro(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#000000")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrás que guardar esa información en algún lugar externo para que se conserve entre ejecuciones.

Podrías por ejemplo escribirlo en un fichero de texto cada vez que el usuario lo cambia, y al arrancar el programa comprobar si ese fichero de texto existe, en caso afirmativo, leerlo y cargar el color.

Por ejemplo, las funciones que cambian el color deberían ser:

```py
def violeta_clarito(self):
    self.root4.config(bg="#B39DDB")
    self.color = "violeta clarito"
    with open('config.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write("#B39DDB")
```

Y en el `__init__` deberías poner algo como:

```py
if Path('config.txt').is_file():
    with open('config.txt', 'r') as f:
        self.root4.config(bg=f.read())
```

Para lo que deberías importar path:

```py
from pathlib import Path
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!